# What connected graphs are with equal vertex-connectivity and minimum degree?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Let $G$ be a connected graph with equal vertex connectivity and minimum degree. What can we say about $G$? I am trying to find some literature about this question, but I was not able to. I will appreciate for your comments.

Thanks

Comment: An $n-$cycle will have be $2-$connected and vertex degree $2$.

Comment: This might be more interesting if we talk about d-regular graphs.

Comment: That might be a good initiator to find some characterization.